# Google Sheets dynamic scoring/ranking

Tags: google-sheets

I have 16 golfers, 16 placement points, and 5 courses. My goal is that each individual can manually enter in their golf score into a google sheet and the formula will take those scores and rank them automatically and provide them scores. When a person doesn't post a score that person should automatically receive 0 points and in this case the worst score of the 15 people who did post a score would receive the points allocated for 15th place, and so on. When there is a tie for example if two people who posted the lowest scores (88, and 88). They would be given the points from both first place and second place. 500 and 440 (940) / 2 (because two golfers tied), and they would both receive 470 points each. The next best score would receive 390. The score distribution would be as followed:
1, 500
2, 440
3, 390
4, 340
5, 300
6, 260
7, 220
8, 190
9, 160
10, 130
11, 100
12, 80
13, 60
14, 40
15, 20
16, 0)

I have built this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, "<="&B2) <= 15,
SWITCH(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, "<="&B2),
1, 500,
2, 440,
3, 390,
4, 340,
5, 300,
6, 260,
7, 220,
8, 190,
9, 160,
10, 130,
11, 100,
12, 80,
13, 60,
14, 40,
15, 20,
0),
IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, B2) > 1,
SUM(SWITCH(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, "<="&B2),
1, 500,
2, 440,
3, 390,
4, 340,
5, 300,
6, 260,
7, 220,
8, 190,
9, 160,
10, 130,
11, 100,
12, 80,
13, 60,
14, 40,
15, 20,
0)) / COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, B2),
"")))
```

However, for some reason those who are tying for first place are getting 440 points and not 470 points and cannot figure out why.

Comment: split it out into bits and check the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell C2, and copy to the bottom of the player scores:

`=average(arrayformula(vlookup(sequence(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, B2),1,rank(B2,$B$2:$B$17,1),1),rank_points!$A$2:$B$17,2,0)))`

It is most likely that this formula can be expressed in the form of `MAP(LAMBDA)` which would make it unnecessary to copy down the column of players.

---

**Logic**

- rank: `rank(B2,$B$2:$B$17,1)`
- count ties: `COUNTIF($B$2:$B$17, B2)`
- create array of rank/ties places: `sequence(D2,1,C2,1)`
- lookup the points for the rank/tied places: `arrayformula(vlookup(sequence(D2,1,C2,1),$M$3:$N$18,2,0))`
- calculate average of the points: `=average(arrayformula(vlookup(sequence(D2,1,C2,1),$M$3:$N$18,2,0)))`

---

**Results**

[image: results]

**Sheet: rank_points**

[image: rankspoints]